# Generate a list from a distinct values of a column mysql, nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a mysql table with a field named "year". I want to create a list from distinct values from the year column. my expected output is,

```
[2011,2013,2014,2015]
```

but what I receive when I try `SELECT DISTINCT year FROM table_name` is,

```
[
  { year: 2012 },
  { year: 2018 },
  { year: 2017 },
  { year: 2014 },
  { year: 2015 },
  { year: 2020 },
  { year: 2019 },
  { year: 2016 },
  { year: 2011 },
  { year: 2013 }
]
```

When I try `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year) AS year` returned `[ { year: '2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020' } ]`.

Please suggest me a method to get the output in my expected format.

My final goal is to create a dict like this from sql query,

```
{
    "years":[2011,2012,....], // distinct years
    "int_colors":["red","green",], // distinct colors
    "min-date":"2020-11-01", 
    "prices":{
        "min": 0, //min value of price column
        "max": 0 max value of price column
    }
}
```

I need to do this using only a single sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it on client side. used the following sql query,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year) AS years, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT int_color) AS int_colors, 
MIN(price2) AS price_min, MAX(price2) AS price_max
FROM table_name
```

result is

```
[
  {
    years: '2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020',
    int_colors: 'ash,beiege,beige,black,black pearl,black/alloy,black/brazen gold,black/diesel gray,black/ruby red,brown,brown/tan,charcoal,coral red,dark ash,dark atmosphere/loft brown,dark slate gray,ebony,ebony w/cirrus headlining and ebony/cirrus ip,graphite,gray,jet black,mocha,newmarket tan,red,sand beige,tan,white',
    ext_colors: 'alpine white,amp,anvil clear coat,billet clearcoat,black,black amethyst,black clear coat,blizzard pearl,blue,brilliant black crystal pearl coat,brilliant silver metallic,brllian silver metallic,crystal white pearl,destroyer gray clear coat,destroyer grey,diamond black clear coat,glacier white,granite crystal metallic clear coat,granite pearl coat,gravity gray,gray,gun metalic,gun metallic,hallmark,island blue metallic,magnetic metallic,mandarin gold metallic,maximum steel metallic clear coat,pepperdust metallic,per mfg,pitch black,polar white,red,silver,silver lining metallic,super black,torred redcoat,true blue pearl coat,white,white knuckle clear coat,white knuckle clearcoat,yellow,yellow jacket clear coat',
    price_min: 10895,
    price_max: 85995
  }
]
```

So I have converted it to the expected format in client site.